# Щетка в значении расческа

Tags: лексика

Допустимо ли употреблять слово щетка в значении расческа? В словаре этого значения нет, в Интернете встречаю.

ЩЁТКА, -и; мн. род. -ток, дат. -ткам; ж. 1. Приспособление для чистки, мытья, обметания и т.п. в виде плоской колодки с часто насаженными пучками щетины или заменяющим её материалом (синтетическими волокнами, проволокой и т.п.). Зубная щ. Массажная щ. Щ. для обуви. Маленькая мягкая щ. Густая жёсткая синтетическая щ. Мыть ванну щёткой. Чистить что-л. щёткой.

При запросе **щетка** приходят щетки, и для волос тоже.

Comment: _Щётка для волос_ (или для шерсти) была и до интернета, по конструкции она отличается от расчёски (= плоский инструмент с неподвижными зубьями), поэтому слово "расчёска" словом "щётка" не заменить. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A9%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Викисловарь в статье "щётка" приводит "расчёску" (гребень) в качестве одного из значений:

> **Щётка**.
>
> *разг.* **гребень** ◆ *На следующий год эту прическу сменила другая ― ежиком, и весь возраст принялся усердно взъерошивать волосы кверху
>   щетками.* А. И. Куприн, «На переломе (Кадеты)», 1900 г.

Судя по цитате, такое употребление не является новым. Хотя с распространением в наше время массажных щёток для головы, которые по совместительству могут быть использованы как расчёски, это значение распространилось и, думаю, со временем будет узаконено.

Comment: Щётки для волос были изобретены за полвека до написания. Но расчёсками их до сих пор не называют - возможно, потому, что они не "расчёсывают" (просто укладывая волосья), а дают _начёс_, затрагивая структуру волоса.

Comment: Спасибо,Александр! вы правы: наверное,поэтому не называют. Даже не додумался!

Comment: Я почему-то называл эти  щетки "расческами".

Comment: @Серж Но ведь в вопросе Вы с точностью до наоборот спросили: можно ли слово щётка употреблять в значении расчёска? То есть Вы произносите слово "щётка" имея в виду расчёску. (И кстати, в толковом словаре Ушакова "щётка для волос" упомянута в статье "щётка".)

Comment: @Alex_ander _Но расчёсками их до сих пор не называют_ Посмотрите внимательнее вопрос, пожалуйста, и мой ответ. Не имеет значения, как не называют щётки. Вопрос был о том, что называют щётками.

Comment: @grizzly, дело в том, что я не знал, что они называются щетками. Я называл их расческами.

Comment: Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: @Серж Понял! Только сейчас дошло :)